# emacs lisp manual

Tags: help, manual

What does this text mean, in node `Simple Lambda Expression Example` of the Emacs Lisp manual:

> As these examples show, you can use a form with a lambda expression as
> its car to make local variables and give them values.  In the old days
> of Lisp, this technique was the only way to bind and initialize local
> variables.  But nowadays, it is clearer to use the special form `let`
> for this purpose

The use of `let` is clear to me, but what does car have to do with this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Good afternoon. Explain why you provided this link? I am translating the manual into Russian, so such questions arise.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the question. I removed tag `elisp` from it; that's all. That tag isn't for questions about using Elisp to do something. It's for questions about the nature of the language, in particular compared to other Lisp dialects. The linked explanation covers the purpose of the tag.

Comment: And thanks for translating the Elisp manual! That's a great undertaking.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application of a lambda expression was used to populate the local variables in the expression, so for example what you can today write as

```
(let ((x 12))
  (message (number-to-string (- (* 4 x) (/ x 2)))))
```

you wrote as

```
((lambda (x)
   (message (number-to-string (- (* 4 x) (/ x 2)))))
 12)
```

The lambda expression is the car of the whole form.

Comment: Thank you, it looks believable.